# IOS 5 sdk updating issue on iphone 3G

Tags: ios, xcode

After sdk updating on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 from 4.1 to 5.0,  cocos2d application won't run on iphone 3G, but it is  runing on Iphone 4S, when first time after updating i was connect iphone to mac, xcode asked me about to install debugging tool for ios 4.1, and after this nothing was happened when i run the application, but on simulator it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 3g need architecture ARVM6, in new XCode this architecture isn't added to projects. You need to add architecture for your project settings and target in XCode. How to add architecture https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329164/1180406. Must be http://qblx.co/z8JaP1

And XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> and install all package what you see http://qblx.co/A5On1G

I have iPhone 2g and that work for me.