# "undefined symbols for architecture" for XCode 4.5.2

Tags: iphone, sdk, xcode4.5

I'm trying to integrate Apsalar Metrics into my App and followed the documentation.
However I'm getting the following Error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Apsalar", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've added all the frameworks that were required to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Apsalar Metrics library (I assume there is one) compiled only for armv6?  If so, you're best to get a new updated version or you can use an earlier version of XCode that will handle armv6 builds.  If you can't get a later version, you can try this hack I wrote for another library: [How to use armv6 third party libraries in an armv7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625253/how-to-use-armv6-third-party-libraries-in-an-armv7-app)  If you're unsure, you can follow the directions in the link to determine what you're compiled with.

Comment: Hey Owen, I guess it is compiled only for armv6. But that's ridiculous since I downloaded the SDK for XCode 4.5.2. and they should be aware of this!! I have gone through the documentation in detail. however to no help. But thanks a lot for the link!!!... it helped me a lot in understanding what could be an issue.... Never thought of that!!.. Appreciate it!!..

Comment: If you have the source code, you can recompile it for armv7, or you can use the hack if there's no other way.  I had to wait two years to get an armv7 version of a third party library, and the hack allowed me to continue to update my app, until they finally got around to shipping the update.

Answer (score 0):

I am the product support engineer at Apsalar and have seen this issue before.

When you added the Apsalar files, did you select "Create Folder References for any added folders" This can cause your error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Apsalar", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

To cover everything, you added the libsqlite3.0dylib, SystemConfiguration.framework, Security.framework, and AdSupport.framework? This may have something to do with the linker problem, especially if you have your Architectures set to armv7, armv7s in your Build Settings. Sometimes 'Clean all Targets' (Product > Clean) and quitting Xcode could work.

I made this tutorial video on installing the SDK. It's 3-4 minutes long and covers integratino from start to finish: www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq68XSJ98Hk&feature=youtu.be